# Unable to print form element

Tags: 7, forms, commerce, hooks

I am not able to get form element qty twice. I have 2 line item IDs, but I am getting 1 instead of printing qty twice. Please help me out this. This is my code.

```
function mol_split_delivery_form($form, &$form_state, $order_id) {

$order = arg(1);
$line_item_idds = get_total_line_item_ids($order);

if (!empty($line_item_idds)) {
  $line_items = commerce_line_item_load_multiple($line_item_idds);

}
else {
  $line_items = array();
}

foreach ($line_items as $line_item_id => $line_item) {

$form = array();
$option_first = array(1 => '1', 2 => '2', 3 => '3', 4 => '4', 5 => '5', 6 => '6', 7 => '7', 8 => '8', 9 => '9');
$form['line_items'][$line_item_id]['quantity'] = array(
    '#title' => 'Qty',
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => $option_first,
    '#default_value' =>  $line_item->quantity,
 );

 }
return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take the `$form = array();` line out of the foreach loop. This is clearing the $form array every time it loops around. You don't want it to do that.

```
foreach ($line_items as $line_item_id => $line_item) {

   $option_first = array(1 => '1', 2 => '2', 3 => '3', 4 => '4', 5 => '5', 6 => '6', 7 => '7', 8 => '8', 9 => '9');

   $form['line_items'][$line_item_id]['quantity'] = array(
     '#title' => 'Qty',
     '#type' => 'select',
     '#options' => $option_first,
     '#default_value' =>  $line_item->quantity,
   );
}
```

Also, if `$order_id` is a argument, you should not need to call `arg(1)`. Consider passing the commerce order object as an argument instead, using %commerce_order as a URL parameter. Drupal will load it and pass it for you (if this function is a menu item callback).

Comment: Yeah its working.Thank you so much Kevin for your time & suggestion.well one day i'll definatly help you back.